# Which of these is the correct statement of Wilson's theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology, factorial

My textbook states:
If $p$ is a prime, then $(p-1) \equiv -1\pmod p$.

But the online version is $(p-1)! \equiv -1\pmod p$.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both are correct, but the first one is trivial rather than deserving to be named after Wilson.

Comment: Which book is it?

Comment: My book has $(p-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: Everything written in textbooks is also modulo possible typos.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The **second one** is Wilson's theorem.

Though the first one is not absurd, since

$$p\equiv 0\pmod p$$

you always have

$$p-1\equiv -1\pmod p$$

whether $p$ is prime or not.

Comment: The first one isn't absurd, but calling it "Somebody's Theorem" is.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, by the powers vested in me by the State of Insanity, I'm officially calling $(p − 1) ≡ −1 (\mod p)$ to be "Somebody's Theorem".

Comment: @BenHocking That's absurd!